# Sending UDP calls in unity on android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, udp

I'm trying to send UDP packets back and forth from a tablet and laptop. My problem is I can't send packets from my android tablet to my laptop. I can send packets from my laptop to itself using both 127.0.0.1 and it's local ip 10.1.10.xxx . I can also send packets from my laptop to the android tablet using it's ip 10.1.10.yyy. I can also send packets from the tablet to itself using both ip address 127.0.0.1 and 10.1.10.yyy. I don't think this is a router setting issue. I'm using code from https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-udp-implementation-send-read-via-mono-c.15900/

Send Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System;


public class Send : MonoBehaviour {

    public string IP;
    public int port;

    public void SendNetworkMessage(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("Testing");
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        Debug.Log("Created Socket");
        byte[] sendbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, port);

        s.SendTo(sendbuf, ep);

        Debug.Log("Message Sent");
    }
}
```

Receive Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Receive : MonoBehaviour {

    public int port;

    UdpClient listener;
    IPEndPoint groupEP;

    Thread receiveThread;


    public void Start()
    {
        receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
        receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        receiveThread.Start();

    }
    public void OnDisable()
    {
        if(receiveThread != null)
        {
            receiveThread.Abort();
        }
        listener.Close();
    }
    public void Listen()
    {
        listener = new UdpClient(port);
        groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.Log("Waiting for broadcast");
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

                Debug.Log("Received broadcast from " + groupEP);
                Debug.Log(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Debug.Log(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
I tested this in the android emulator using the same version of android as on the tablet and it works. I don't know of a setting on device where it could receive data but not send it.

Comment: Check your firewall settings. Probably your computer is blocking incoming requests due to firewall rules. You can temporary disable it to check or allow requests from the tablet specific port.